# Making lock screen notifications show only in drop-down menu

Tags: notifications, lock-screens

Using oneplus 3t, Android 7.0, oxygen OS 4.0.3, not rooted.
I'm trying to get my lock screen notifications to only be visible when I slide down the notification bar, and show the app icons on th top right. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Notification -> Tap on settings icon on right top and click "On the lock screen" -> Don't show notification at all.And for second one (app icons on the top right) is not possible with default lock screen in OP3. Instead you can use LED notification light for the apps or use a custom lock screen app which will disable smartlock.